# Auto-generating user email when creating user profile?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I am creating a application using django

My Code as follows:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    Name = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    E_mail = models.EmailField(max_length=70)
    Phone_no = models.BigIntegerField()
    Skills = models.TextField()
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_images')
```

I want to autogenerate the user email in the user profile which the user had given at the time of signup.

I am using the django autheticated models for signup and login and I am using class based views for my profile generation.

Can anybody help me in this?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your statement, **autogenerate the user email in the user profile which the user had given at the time of signup**. Do you mean user doesn't have to provide his email in signup process, system will automatically generate a email and assign to the user?

Comment: No I dont actually mean that...I mean when the user will sign up he/she will provide some email to complete the signup process...I want to get that email which the user provided during signup in every page of my django project...@SazzadurRahman

Comment: The model I have mentioned in my question is not for my signup page...

Comment: Then why don't you **just query** the database for the email in the pages where it's necessary. Or you want it to be kind of a global variable for which you don't have to explicitly query each time?

Comment: I want it like this for example if we want to get the username we just have to do {{ user.get_username }} in our template...Is there any alternative way like this for email???

Answer (score 1):

For this case you can leverage Django's [custom context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) for template.

Create a file `context_processors.py` in your main app folder which will contain your user object, like this:

```
def user(request):
    return {'user': {'email': request.user.email if request.user.is_authenticated else None}}
```

Then in `settings.py` file add your context processors's name under `context_processors` list, like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'myapp.context_processors.user',  # This is our custom context processors
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Now you can access user email in all templates with this syntax,`{{ user.email }}`